# Find MSBuildProjectDirectory Parent Directory

Tags: msbuild

MSBuild 3.5

I have the following project structure:

```
trunk/MainSolution.sln
trunk/Build/MyBuild.Proj
trunk/Library/...
trunk/etc...
```

So far, I've been using the following property to find out the project root folder:

```
<RootFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\</RootFolder>
```

Everything was working great, until I tried using a copy task that relied on this path. It is not resolving correctly. I basically end up getting something like this which is not valid:

```
C:\Projects\MyProject\Trunk\Build\..\CodeAnalysis\myfile.xml
```

So basically, I need to get the full path for (MSBuildProjectDirectory)'s Parent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Item metadata is your friend!

```
<Target Name="GetMSBuildProjectParentDirectory">
  <!-- First you create the MSBuildProject Parent directory Item -->
  <CreateItem Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\">
    <Output ItemName="MSBuildProjectParentDirectory" TaskParameter="Include"/>
  </CreateItem>

  <!-- You can now retrieve its fullpath using Fullpath metadata -->
  <Message Text="%(MSBuildProjectParentDirectory.Fullpath)"/>

  <!-- Create a property based on parent fullpath-->
  <CreateProperty Value="%(MSBuildProjectParentDirectory.Fullpath)">
    <Output PropertyName="CodeFolder" TaskParameter="Value"/>
  </CreateProperty>
</Target>
```

Comment: That looks great! Do you know how I can use this to create a variable with the path?

e.g. 

<CodeFolder>%(MSBuildParentDirectory.Fullpath)</CodeFolder>

But obviously that doesn't work...

Comment: Properties are evaluated before target execution, you must use the CreateProperty task (see my edit)

Comment: Ok, so you are saying I have to use the create property task? The reason I ask is because I currently have about 5 properties that need this path.

e.g. CodeFolder, DBFolder, DeployFolder, etc...

Comment: If you absolutely need 5 properties, yes that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays with MSBuild 4.0 and above you don't want to use CreateItem or CreateProperty tasks anymore. What you are asking for can be solved easily with msbuild property functions:

```
<!-- Prints the parent directory's full path. -->
$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..'))
```

If you just want to read the parent directory's folder name you can combine the above statement with the GetFileName property function:

```
$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName('$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..'))'))
```

A bit verbose but much better than the other answer as this works outside of targets and can be assigned to a property.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone like me is still interested in this, here is how I did it in 2022 ^_^

```xml
<PropertyGroup> 
    <ParentFolderPath>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</ParentFolderPath>
    <ParentFolder>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($(ParentFolderPath)))</ParentFolder>
...
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm using this technique to auto-name the assemblies and default namespaces in the complex solutions.

```
<AssemblyName>$(ParentFolder).$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
<RootNamespace>$(ParentFolder).$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
```