# get parent directory in MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild, nant

In NAnt i have a very simple property to get the root of my project, it looks like this.:

```
<property
name="project.root.folder" 
value="${directory::get-parent-directory(directory::get-parent-directory(project.local.folder))}"
/>
```

This takes me up to the root of my project from which I build all my paths.

In MSBuild I can use `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` to get my current directory but i would like to get the full path of the parent directory.  NAnt uses `directory::get-parent-directory` which works a charm and i'm hoping there is something similar available in MSBuild.

I found a previous similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514264/msbuild-find-msbuildprojectdirectory-parent-directory) but I am thinking there must be something simpler available, surely!

Sam : )

Comment: Looks like what? Aha, fixed it for you!

Comment: haha, not sure how you did that but thanks!

Comment: BAMBAM: Indent with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is MSBuild 4.0.  You can do this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <RootFolder>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</RootFolder>
</PropertyGroup>
<Message Text="RootFolder: '$(RootFolder)'" />
```

Comment: seems to be version 3.5, shame, maybe its time to upgrade!

Comment: Is this a VS 2010 project, or 2008?

Comment: Won't that just give you the project directory back? The same as if you used $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) itself?

Comment: No, System.IO.Path doesn't know if you give it a path to a directory or a file, it treats them the same.  I'm passing it a full path to a folder, and it strips the lowest level folder off of it, presuming that it is the file name, and giving the folder above.  Try it!

Comment: @Spider M9 - I would, but I'm in the middle of the woods in another country on a SDN-M with 512k of bandwidth piped through a SSH/SOCKS tunnel on a system running off a generator.

Comment: @Spider M9 - upgraded to 4.0, whacked it in, BAM! Thanks very much. : )

Comment: For some reason the path is returned with a space on the end and although I can now use trim() I cant seem to use it on that property so here's what Ive gone with...

  <RootFolderDirty>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(MSBuildProjectDirectory))) </RootFolderDirty>
  <RootFolder>$(RootFolderDirty.trim())</RootFolder>
  <OutputFolder>$(RootFolder)\output</OutputFolder>

Comment: You have an extra space in the declaration of <RootFolderDirty>, just before the closing element.  Not sure if that is intentional as an example, or just an oversight, but that whitespace will become part of the property.

Answer (score 1):

The question you posted has your answer, and it looks to be a decent one. MSBuild is built around projects and not solutions, so finding something to give you a solution path requires a bit of customization. One fact to consider is that for many projects solution files aren't located at the root of the project tree (or 'cone' in MSBuild parlance).

[MSBuild Reserved Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx)

Comment: That gives me the path C:\GIT\NAntTest\build and I want C:\GIT\NAntTest as a property so I can then use it as a starting block for all my relative URLs

Comment: BAMBAM - Oh you want the full solution path! Got it. (assuming the project is relative to the solution).